# 'java.lang.Object javax.inject.Provider.get()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, dagger

Why the following code template is getting null pointer exception ? what did i do wrong or left to do?

annotation

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {}
```

module

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent.class)
public interface MyModule {
   @Provide
   @MyAnnotation 
   public static ConfirmationOverlay provideConfirmation() {
       return new ConfirmationOverlay();
   }
}
```

Used like below

```
@Inject @MyAnnotation  Provide<ConfirmationOverlay> confOverlay;

............


private void aMethod() {
   confOverlay.get(); ======> throws null pointer exception 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I make my best guess Because you omitted from where `aMethod()` is being called.

As Hilt injects the `Activity` members in its `super.onCreate`, I think you are probably calling `aMethod()` just right before that.

Comment: No, aMethod() is called for a button action event. obviously super.onCreate is called before that once. the button action caught on the activity where ConfirmationOverlay was injected